# How to Plot Y-axis labels on right hand side of Android Chart

Tags: android, achartengine

I am using `XYMultipleSeriesRenderer  buildRenderer` to draw the chart....
I don't want to use canvas.

any solution??

I don't want to flip whole graph just put the Y-axis or Y-labels on the Right-Hand-Side instead of default left side.

```
|


|

                     30
|

                     20

                     10
|---------------------------
```

Comment: are you using achartengine to draw a chart?

Comment: yes........................................................milind

Comment: ok, can u explain in brief ? what u want exactly?

Comment: basically Y-labels appears on the left hand side of the chart but I want arrange labels vertically on right-side of screen..

Comment: There is no default API which in achartengine which will do it. You need to change the code for this customization.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

import new 0.7.0 library of achartengine and just do....

```
renderer.setYAxisAlign(Align.CENTER,0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try putting a second view which displays the labels to the right hand side of the main view. I did that when I had to create a second Y axis on a graph.